# Cannot find symbol in JUnit Test

Tags: java, junit

I have to use JUnit Test to check my classes and somehow can't get them to work. The very simple test I'm trying looks like this:

```
@Test
    public void points_shouldCreatInstance() {
        assertEquals(1.0f,2.0f, Point.Point(1.0f,2.0f));
    }
```

and I'm trying to test this class:

```
public class Point {

    float x;
    float y;

    public Point(float x, float y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public float get_x(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public float get_y(){
        return this.y;
    }
...
}
```

But Netbeans tells me, that it can't find the symbol (second) Point in `Point.Point(1.0f,2.0f));`
I'm sure it's obvious, but I wasn't able to find any well written documentations about JUnit.

Comment: `public Point(float x, float y)` is a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), that's what gets called by `new Point(1.0f, 1.0f)`. `Point.Point` would refer to a static method on that class, which (as the error tells you) you don't have. This is **nothing to do with JUnit**, you are apparently not familiar with Java OOP.

Comment: Be more specific than *"doesn't work"*. If you mean the test doesn't pass; of course it doesn't, that's not how you use `assertEquals`. Your test doesn't actually make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

`Point(1.0f,2.0f)` **is a constructor call**, not `static` method call (you should NOT use dot operator), so you can't call like `Point.Point(1.0f,2.0f))`, which is incorrect.
Here, in order to test the `Point` class, you need to create the `Point` class object using `new` operator like `new Point(1.0f,2.0f)`.

The correct way to test the `Point` class is shown in the below code with comments:

```
     @Test
     public void points_shouldCreatInstance() {
       //Create Point object (calls Point class constructor)
       Point point = new Point(1.0f,2.0f);

        //Check x is set inside the created Point object
        assertEquals(1.0f, point.get_x());

        //Check y is set inside the created Point object
        assertEquals(2.0f, point.get_y());
    }
```